# Very strange behavior in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've run into very strange behavior in awk.

The input file is the following:

```
               ABCD                                        Yes
               EFGH                                        Yes
```

My awk script is the following:

```
/^              / {
        print "ss", $2, "dd\n"
}
```

What I'm expecting is the following:

```
ss Yes dd

ss Yes dd
```

But, suprisingly, the result is the following:

```
 ddYes

 ddYes
```

Where is my "ss" and how come Yes attached in the back of "dd"?

Comment: Can't reproduce that. What is the value of `OFS` ?

Comment: Your files have DOS newlines. That's `\r` resetting the insertion to the start of the line. Change the `ss` prefix length or the `dd` suffix length and you'll see it.

Comment: You command works just fine for me. I am on `GNU Awk 3.1.8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input file has DOS newlines. The `\r` character at the end of each line is getting output as part of `$2` and resetting the insertion point to the start of the line at which point the space from `,` and `dd` are then printed out overwriting the initial `ss`. (You can modify either the `ss` prefix or the `dd` suffix length to see this more clearly.)

Strip those from the original file and this will go away.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{print "ss", $2, "dd\n"}' f2
```

`f2` is input file and its working fine for me